# How to unit test a method that returns a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, flask

I have two Python scripts: let's call them program.py and program_utils.py.

program.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import program_utils

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/mypage')
def my_func():
  # Do some stuff here and get a URL parameter
  my_var = request.args.get('my_var')
  # Get JSON object from another function in program_utils
  return program_utils.get_json_object(my_var)
```

get_json_object() in program_utils.py looks like this:

```
def get_json_object(my_var):
  # Do some calls to other methods to create the JSON object using my_var
  return json_object
```

My question is how do I create a unit test for get_json_object in program_utils to ensure that it is returning the object in the correct format? I have tried writing a regular unit test (treating the method as if it returned a string) but was presented with a run time error saying "working outside of application context".

Comment: You could treat this as an integration test, rather than a unit test - call the endpoint and verify you get valid `application/json`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the test client to test Flask views.  Create it with `app.test_client()` and then use it to simulate requests to your routes.  The response only has the raw data, if you want to compare it as JSON you'll need to load it.

```
c = app.test_client()
rv = c.get('/mypage', query_string={'my_var': 'my_value'})
assert json.loads(rv.get_data()) == expected_data
```

The [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/) have a whole section devoted to introducing this.  The [Werkzeug docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder) go into more detail.